# The equivalent of baccalauréat diploma for the Anglo-American educational system

Tags: professions

In professional life, it is necessary to know the English way of expressing your level of education.

As you know, the **baccalauréat** is the diploma awarded to those finishing their secondary education.

In America, is it a “bachelor’s degree”, a “high school diploma”, or something else?

Comment: It might be important to mention what country you finished your *enseignement secondaire* in.

Comment: Tunisia .. it is

Comment: In Britain students generally need to have passed 3-5 [**A levels**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-levels) (which are in specific subjects) in "secondary" education in order to progress to [tertiary education](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_education) (degrees, etc.).

Comment: A levels are not the final exams/qualifications gained from school. Those are **GCSEs** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Certificate_of_Secondary_Education A levels come after them and are the next stage of secondary education.

Comment: @Fumble I'd thought that UK tertiary education **was** sixth-form (A-levels) and university was *higher education*. Perhaps these things have changed, like so much in eduation, since I was there.

Comment: @Andrew: It's certainly changed since ***I*** was there! I only actually scraped my third A Level with a grade D, but unless I'd been desperate to go to Oxbridge I could have prolly have got in to most universities with just two. Today's teenagers routinely take 4 or 5 A Levels, and they usually reckon on needing at least 3 *good* grades to ensure a reasonable choice of degree course. But check the link in my earlier comment. I certainly wouldn't count "sixth form colleges" as tertiary education.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In North America, "High school" is the school that most students attend when they are aged 14-18 (grades 9-12). Typically, this results in a "high school diploma". This schooling is also called ["Secondary school"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_school#North_America).

Note that this varies depending on the jurisdiction. For example, in Quebec, "Secondary" school is from grades 6-11.

From what Wikipedia tells me about the Tunisian educational system, the baccalauréat is a high-school diploma.

A [Bachelor's degree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor%27s_degree) is earned after secondary school (post-secondary) and is also known as an undergraduate degree. It is earned in universities or colleges (but again, the specific terminology depends on the jurisdiction: in Ontario, a *college* does not grant degrees).

You need to familiarize yourself with the educational system of the specific place whose system you wish to compare to. They are all different.

Comment: Quebec's secondary school starts in grade 7, not 6.